# How to retain the state of JQuery Accordion menu (on postback) inside updatepanel

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, postback, jquery-ui-accordion

i want to **retain the state of jquery accordion menu** *on post back* **inside a updatepanel**.

i've tried the bellow code but by default on all postback happening inside the menu its opening the first menu always.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfaccordion" runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Menu ID="mnuTest" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
            onmenuitemclick="mnuTest_MenuItemClick">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="View 1" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="View 2" Value="1" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="View 3" Value="2"></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>

        <asp:MultiView ID="mvwTest" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View ID="vwOne" runat="server">

            <div id="accordion">
                <h3><a href="#">Menu 1</a></h3>
                <div>
                    Test 1
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Post" />
                </div>

                <h3><a href="#">Menu 2</a></h3>
                <div>
                    Test 2
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var active = $('#<%= hfaccordion.ClientID %>').val();
                var currentindex= 0;
                    if (active != '') {
                        currentindex = active;
                    }

                $("#accordion").accordion(
                {
                    change: function(event, ui) {
                        var i = $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active");
                            $('#<%= hfaccordion.ClientID %>').val(i);
                        }
                    }
                );

                $("#accordion").accordion("activate", parseInt(currentindex));
            });

            function pageLoad(){
                $("#accordion").accordion(
                {
                    change: function(event, ui) {
                        var i = $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active");
                            $('#<%= hfaccordion.ClientID %>').val(i);
                        }
                    }
                );

                //$("#accordion").accordion();
                //var activeMenu = localStorage.getItem('am');
                //$("#accordion").accordion( "activate" , parseInt(activeMenu));
            }
            </script>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vwTwo" runat="server">
            <div>
                <p>view 2</p>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </div>
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="vwThree" runat="server">
            <div>
                <p>view 3</p>
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </div>
        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

its urgent. thanks in advance...

Comment: As longs as current active accordion index is being updated in hidden field ,and you JS part working fine, hidden field's value should automatically be preserved during postbacks. If not make sure you have enabled `ViewState` for your page.